# Как редактировать формат отправки email-сообщений woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Нужно изменить структуру отправки сообщений на почту, поменять переменные местами, переименовать поля и убрать лишнее. Вопрос в том, какой из файлов woocommerce отвечает конкретно за составление html-шаблона отправки писем?

Comment: Без конкретики, это ребус.

Comment: [ссылка](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-add-a-custom-woocommerce-email/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо, разобрался. Ошибка в php коде была и вражда с плагином кастомизации емэйлов для woo.

Answer (score 0):

http://take.ms/gYq5Q - как видите на каждое действие свой темплейт,
http://take.ms/JMYMR - надо скопировать в тему какой надо редактировать и тут уже над ним колдовать.

Comment: Да, я это сделал, но в этих файлах идёт только вызов определённых функций обработки, исходный код их смотрел - не помогло. Не намёка на html-шаблон.

Comment: @ВикторТимошков - http://take.ms/cFCmq - есть же верстка... Попробуйте заглянуть сюда woocommerce\templates\emails/plain/email-order-items.php - может это именно то что вы хотите. Если нет. Уточните вопрос, какое поле вам надо поменять.

Comment: @Gakina Bublik Да, именно это я и изменял. Я просто менял местами некоторые элементы и выдавало Server Internal Error,

Comment: @ВикторТимошков, видимо из-за ошибок в коде( попробуйте поменять текст, без перемещения кода. Если ошибки не будет - внимательней меняйте поля с сохранением структуры пхп кода. !Текмплейт надо перенести в тему!